# How to display the scan results in Android?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I want to display the scan result from ZXING. I integrated ZXING into my android app, the scan works ok. Now I want to use the scan result to update a TextView in the main activity.

Comment: you can get the code from onhanledecode function.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent("<span class="skimlinks- unlinked">com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN</span>");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Getting result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
         // Handle successful scan
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
      }
   }
}
```

Follow [this](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) tutorial for more info

Comment: should i have to change in any other classes too like result handler or in capture activity?? this thing is not working as my app is integrated with zxing.

Comment: no you can do as per the tutorial and check you added permissions in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String contents = null;
String format=null;
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
     format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
     //moved here
     TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanFormat);
     tv1.setText(format);


     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
     tv.setText(contents);
     // Handle successful scan
  } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
     // Handle cancel
  }
}
```

and add this too in your activity

```
  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }
```

and in manifest file in tour activity :

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: i also want to show for the type/format of the barcode but it is not present as in type of intent...can you help me..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully develop Barcode Scanning app with the help of
[Create a Barcode Scanner usingg Zxing library](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)

It might be helpful as well.. or anyone looking to develop barcode scanning app!!

Comment: my application scan barcode successfully but i am unable to display result of scan. In which class i have to change. i put  onActivityResult method in main activity class but it's not working..can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
        historyManager.trimHistory();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
        //Log.d(TAG ,"ITEM NUMBER =>" +itemNumber);
        if (itemNumber >= 0) {
            historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);

            decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
            Log.d(TAG ,"ITEM NUMBER =>" +historyItem.getResult());
        }
```